# jQuery or Javascript solution for radio buttons and showing/ hiding divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, show-hide

I have, what on initial viewing, is a simple requirement to `show/hide` two `divs` based on a users response to radio buttons.

See the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P75cv/

The real complexity is as follows.

Div `one` is to be shown if any of the questions has a radio button value of 2 or 1.
Div `two` is **only** to be shown if any of the questions don't have a value of 2, 1 or -1.

However, I also need a further check to do the following, if div `one` has been shown and a user goes back and changes their response so that no radio buttons have a value or 2 or 1, then div `one` needs to be hidden and div `two` shown.  Similarly, if div `two` is being shown but the user goes back and changes their responses so that any of the radio buttons have a value of 2 or 1, div `two` needs to be hidden and div `one` shown.

And finally, the user has the option of saving and coming back to the page - if they do, I need the right div to be shown based (on page load?).

The simple part of showing and hiding divs I can do, in both jQuery and Javascript but this level of complexity is really causing me a headache - can anyone offer an insights or solutions?

Comment: You are asking something so precise and this is not a place where in which people will do your homework... just helping with specific questions. Take some ideas from here, is not that complex: http://jsfiddle.net/eJaQh/1/

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro - looking at the jsFiddle you kindly supplied, it looks like I am going to have to manually iterate through the questions - which is fine if there are only two - one of the reasons for the questions was I was hoping to find a more elegant and efficient way using jQuery when I have say 10 or 20 sets of questions on the page.  I'm not expecting this to be done for me - just ideas and suggestions as I am stuck on this one.

Comment: You can iterate through them in other if you want. It was just an example. If you don't know how to do it in other way, open a new question with that specific doubt.

Comment: Thanks again - I've supplied my own answer below - not pretty but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, answering my own question - I have used the following code:

```
<?php
function checking() {
count = 0;
";
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
echo"   q".$i." = $('input[name=\"q".$i."\"]:checked').val();
    if(q".$i." == 1 || q".$i." == 2){
            document.getElementById('disagree').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('agree').style.display = 'none';
        count = 1;
    }
    ";

    }

    echo" 

    if (count==0){
        document.getElementById('disagree').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('agree').style.display = 'block';
    }

}
?>
```

As you can see, I have 10 questions on the page and use PHP to write the script out and it works.  I have no doubt whatsoever that there are far more efficient and elegant ways of achieving the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would create your basic functions that perform the show/hide routine. Then populate an array that has all the values of the radio buttons, check if the array contains the values you are looking for, and then call the proper function.

I would use JQuery cookie to store what div should be shown when the user saves and comes back to the page.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond - as you can see from my own answer - I've devised a solution...not pretty but it works.